# Selenium web driver not able to close firefox instance if a Test cases is failed

Tags: java, junit4, selenium-webdriver

i folks, 
i am using junit with selenium web driver 2.28.
the problem is if i run a successful test case the web drives is able to close the firefox instance, but when a test case fails the selenium web driver is not able to close the firefox.
i am using FF 15.0.1 with selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar.
please respond
thanks
Sahil

```
private void startWebdriver() throws UIException{
    //2) Prevent re-use.
    if(UIHandlerWD.this.profile == null)
        throw new 
            UIException(
                UIException.Code.UI, 
                    "Webdriver instance cannot be instantiated."
            );              

    //3) Configure Selenium Webdriver.
    if (this.profile.browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("*firefox")){
        FirefoxProfile fProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

       // profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
        fProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fProfile);

        //this.webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        this.webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    }
    else if (this.profile.browserType=="INTERNETEXPLORER")
        this.webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    else
        throw new 
        UIException(
            UIException.Code.UI, 
                "Unknown browser type '" + this.profile.browserType +"'."
        );          


    //4) Start Webdriver.
    this.webdriver.get(this.profile.getURL().toString());
    this.webdriver.manage().timeouts().
    implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.webdriver.manage().timeouts().
    pageLoadTimeout(this.profile.timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

void stopWebdriver() {
    if(this.webdriver != null){
        try{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
        this.webdriver.close();
    }
    this.webdriver = null;
    this.profile = null;
}
```

Comment: Please share a program of how you invoking the above two methods.

Comment: hi,i was debugging the issue, and this is what i found out
- When i am running the whole class then the selenium instance not closing.
But when i am debugging through the code, then when i step over the "this.webdriver.close();",
then the selenium instance is able to close

I am using eclipse indigo 
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

Comment: You can use JUnit annotations...Make use of `@Before for browser setup`, `@Test for test code` and `@After for the browser killing`.

Comment: i am using @AfterClass to stop the selenium session, but still its not working

Comment: i am already using AfterClass to stop the selenium session,
CODE fr calling selenium.stop()
AfterClass
public static void _afterJUnitTestCase() {
previousCtx = TestContext.getContext();
TestContext.removeContext();
currentCase = null;
}
Class used for selenium .stop function
public static void removeContext() {
   //1) Stop Selenium, if started.
   for(UIWD ui: activeContext.uiHandlers.keySet())
   activeContext.stopUI(ui);
  activeContext.uiHandlers.clear();

  //2) Restore the system context.
   activeContext = SYSTEM_CONTEXT;
}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `webdriver.quit()` to an `@AfterClass` method.

close() will shut the current active window.  If the current active window is the last window it is functionally equivalent to performing a quit().

It does however need to have a valid active session to be able to do this. If your test has failed that session is probably dead, so when you call a close() it doesn't know where to send the command and throws an Exception.

quit() will end all sessions and shut down all clients, it's basically a clean up everything command.  It will also not throw any Exceptions if all clients/sessions have already been closed/ended.

Comment: thanks man, it worked 
but i was wondering i am already using webdriver.close()
why is that not wroking??

Comment: Close will shut the current active window and if it is the last window will then perform a quit().  It does however need to have a valid active session to be able to do this. If your test has failed that session is probably dead, so when you call a close it doesn't know where to send the command and doesn't do anything.  Quit will shut down all clients if there are no active sessions so if you send a quit and have no active sessions it will just clean up.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you may want to mark it as a correct answer :)

Comment: @user1863204 The proper way to thank someone on StackOverflow is to accept their answer.