# How to safely end a program with a ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium

Currently I have the following issue:

```
my code is 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.close();
```

But thoissometimes ens in an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562363/selenium-web-driver-not-able-to-close-firefox-instance-if-a-test-cases-is-failed/14696554#14696554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using driver.quit(); Do not use close();
Actually, this is problem, especially if you are using Chrome. Try also sing Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Add `driver.quit()` to an @AfterClass method

Close will shut the current active window and if it is the last window will then perform a quit(), it does however need to have a valid active session to be able to do this.

If your test has failed that session is probably dead, so when you call a close it doesn't know where to send the command and doesn't do anything.

Quit will shut down all clients if there are no active sessions so if you send a quit and have no active sessions it will just clean up